# jumbotron and carousel padding

Tags: jquery

I have a carousel in home page and jumbotron class resides Below that carousel.I give padding-top for the jumbotron. It reflects the other pages not having carousel.It happens only in mobile view.
To fix this issue,I put the following jquery code in .js file

```
if($(".body_content").hasClass( ".carousel" )){
    $(".jumbotron").css({"padding-top":"280px"});
}
else{
    $(".jumbotron").css({"padding-top":"0px","margin-top":"-70px"});
}
```

But this works on all pages including home page.
Can anybody give me the solution? Please give me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Will check if "carousel" exist in page or not.
if ( $( ".carousel" ).length ) { 
    $(".jumbotron").addClass('home-jumbotron');
}else{
    $(".jumbotron").addClass('not-home-jumbotron');
}

//Media query CSS (So it can be affected to mobile view only)
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .home-jumbotron {
          padding-top: 280px;
     }    
    .not-home-jumbotron {
          padding-top: 0px;
          margin-top:-70px
     }
}
```

Comment: But it affects desktop view also.

Comment: How does it effect? Do you want to affect it in mobile view only?

Comment: @SowmiyaP check my updated answer. To get if affected you should have to use media query. And instead of giving CSS you should have to use addClass function of jquery as above

Comment: Sir I have another question. nav bar toggle menu is not expanding in mobile(chrome browser).But it works well in other browsers

Answer (score 0):

assuming that both `divs` are sibilings and are one after the other, you can use the [direct sibiling](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) css selector:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .jumbotron {
          padding-top: 280px;
     }

     .carousel + .jumbotron {
         padding-top: 0;
         margin-top: -70px;
     }
}
```

this applies `padding-top: 0;` `margin-top: -70px;` styles to the `.jumbotron` if a div with a `.carousel` class is preceeding it. otherwise, `padding-top: 280px;` is applied to the jumbotron.

if the `divs` are siblings but not directly one after the other use the [general sibling](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp) css selector:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .jumbotron {
          padding-top: 280px;
     }

     .carousel ~ .jumbotron {
         padding-top: 0;
         margin-top: -70px;
     }
}
```

this will affect screen sizes of 900px and lower (i.e. mobile devices only). you can change the `900px` to suit your needs. more about css3 media queries [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

if they are not siblings try [Rahul Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39308671/6697323)'s answer.

Comment: But it affects desktop view also.